# Path Analysis - Can my model include covariance between residuals of endogenous variables?

Tags: model, structural-equation-modeling, path-model

I am conducting a path analysis and want to include two mediating variables (Variables 3 & 4) which I  believe will be correlated with one another. I don't want to specify the direction of this relationship so I planned on including a bidirectional arrow between these variables. To do this my understanding is that I would include the bidirectional arrow between the residual error terms of these variables.

However I am now looking in to the assumptions of Path Analysis and have come across articles saying that the covariance among residuals are zero / residuals cannot be correlated with each other. Can I include this bidirectional arrow or does this mean I can't use this model as I'm expecting vars 3 & 4 to be correlated?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice

[image]